# Set data for every user after the login?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want every user to have a unique number when he enters this number is attached to his google provider email in firebase data.

Like user, A has number:324492 and no one has the same number but him

ps: I just want to know the method I will use to make something like this and I will do the rest and if the user can make calls with the number later or not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kFlS.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After login you save user Number in shared-preference, and when user logout remove from shared preference.

But you have to check user Number in initState , if you don't login user every time

Comment: will shared preference store the data even after the app is deleted form the mobile

Comment: shared preference store data in app storage, in app is deleted data will be clean